# form post - getURL secure (HTTPS / SSL)

Tags: magento-1, controllers, ssl, https, secure

There is a form post, it sends data without secure URL (HTTP):

```
<form id="answer_form_<?php echo $id;?>" class="form" method="post" action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('productquestions/productquestions/saveanswers',array('product_questions_id'=>$id));?>">
```

How can I change it, so it posts with SSL (HTTPS) ?

Answer (score 4):

You can do so by using the `_secure` parameter:

```
<?php echo Mage::getUrl('productquestions/productquestions/saveanswers',array('product_questions_id'=>$id, '_secure' => true));?>
```